# Is it fair to use accent colors to borders in material design?

Tags: color-theory, data-visualisation, google-material-design

I'm trying to create a widget styles in dashboard design.is it fair to use accent colors to borders instead of background color.when i try to use as bachground color it doesnt compliment the other colors such as header(#3AA9DD) and side menu(#2a3d50) any suggestions would be appreciated.Thanks for the help.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to break from the design pattern, but instead choose a better color that fits in with your color palette. It would be more efficient to change a color slightly than to change a pattern :)